# Fragment View State on Screen Rotation

Tags: android

I have a few fragments that are loaded when a user clicks on an item in a list. Say a user has clicked on second item in the list, loading the second fragment. But, upon rotating, the screen, the first fragment in the list gets loaded. How can I make sure that the same fragment gets loaded whenever a user rotates the screen.
This is how I'm loading my fragments

```
private void selectItem(position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;    
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            break;
         default:
            break;
     }
    if (fragment != null) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    } 
    else {
        Log.e("NavigationActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I'm calling `selectItem(0)` in `onCreate` of an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire activity gets destroyed and recreated during a rotation. So if you are calling setItem(0) in Activity.onCreate, then you'll always get FirstFragment in the content frame.

Seems like the easy thing may be to just detect if you've already set a fragment in onCreate and not load the default.  Either make use of onSaveInstanceState and/or mark the fragment as retained.

I don't have much experience with retained fragments or fragment management beyond initial load, so just using onSaveInstanceState to keep track of which one was loaded seems appropriate.

In your Activity, override onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
    bundle.putInt("which_fragment", _fragmentId);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

Where `_fragmentId` is just some numerical identifier of the particular fragment you are loading. It could even be it's layout id.  Set this value in your selectItem method.

And then in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    _fragmentId = 0;
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        _fragmentId = savedInstanceState.getInt("which_fragment", 0);
    }

    ...

    selectItem(_fragmentId);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. How about I create a variable and store the `position` user's selected, and upon screen rotation, I call `selectItem` with that value instead of 0? Highly theoretically without code but would it work?

Comment: Updated answer.  I think this is going down the same path of what the other answer is suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I wouldn't use `positionOnTheList->Fragment` dependency. I would depend on some `id` (final or from the resources).

Secondly I think you shouldn't create a new instance of each `Fragment` class when you select item from the list.

You should consider this approach:

```
Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentById( String.valueOf(id) );
if( f == null )
    f = new FragmentDependingOnId();
mCurrentlySelectedId = id;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace( R.id.container, f , String.valueOf(id))
            .commit();
```

Add the following method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ID, mCurrentlySelectedId);
}
```

and in `onCreate` add:

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
    mCurrentlySelectedId = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ID);
    selectItem(mCurrentlySelectedId);
}
```

Comment: What is `id` here and why are we storing `id` in `mCurrentlySelectedId`? Could be elaborate the code a bit more? I'm new to Android

Comment: We are storing `id` in `mCurrentlySelectedId` in case the device get's rotated and we need to save it in `outState` `Bundle`

Comment: Moreover, I don't have any ID of the fragment. I'm creating the fragment by `Fragment fragment = null;`

Comment: Sorry, I may have mixed it up a bit. You should use `tag` to find the `Fragment` and assing a `tag` to `Fragment` on fragment transaction. Still the `id` argument in `selectItem` should reference some model data that you are using in your adapter, but I guess for now you might stick to position reference.

Comment: Yup. I've stick to the `position` variable in the activity class as it looked like a cleaner solution to me. Debugging the code now. *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 1):

When using fragment you usually use `onCreateView` to inflate your layout. Then you use `onActivityCreated` to do all the stuff you need to init listviews etc ...

In your case the problem you have is that you should use the saveInstanceState to keep track of if a fragment is loaded or not because the fragment is re-created on each rotation.

Let's look at some code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //do nothing if the state already exists
    } else {
        //do something if state already exists
    }
}
```

Note that if you need to save a given value, for example a boolean you can use

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(YOUR_BOOL_TAG, mYourBooleanVar);
}
```

and get it back in the `onCreateView` by using

```
mYourBooleanVar= savedInstanceState.getBoolean(YOUR_BOOL_TAG);
```

same applies to other types also.

**EDIT**

I didn't quite answered your question, so I put more details. The above code is in the fragment. However for your question, in the `activity` you need something like that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //here is the transaction to load your first fragment
    }
}
```

and your first fragement won't reload each time.

The first time `savedInstanceState` will be null and you set your default fragment. Then each time you rotate `savedInstanceState` is not null and your default fragment is not reloaded but the one that is currently present.

Only this code is relevant for you, but I let the code above the EDIT for other people in case it can be useful to them.

Comment: I've mentioned that I'm calling `selectItem(0)` in `onCreate` of the activity that has the list from which I am loading the fragments.

Comment: Where are you defining `onActivityCreated`? Is it inside the `fragment` class?

Comment: So I just put `selectItem(0)` in the `if` condition of the code in the EDIT section and I'm good to go?

Comment: I just had to call `selectItem` with the value of `position` that I've set in the class. It works perfectly. Thank you :D